# Store Variable from API into MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, asynchronous, async-await

I want to have the fetch `startTime` to be the time I can get from this endpoint:

http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/cet/now

Here is my route:

```
router.get('/new',async(req,res)=>{
    try{
        let myTime = new Time({
            deviceName: 'PS41',
            deviceConsole: 'PS4',
            startTime:  // How Can i Get the Time From The API Here! ,
            endTime: 652585258
        })
        await myTime.save()
        res.send('Done')
    }
    catch(err){res.send(err.message)}
})
```

And thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make an API call there. Here is an example using `request-promise`

```
import request = require('request-promise');

router.get('/new', async (req, res) => {
    try {

        let response: string = await request.get({
            method: 'GET',
            uri: 'http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/cet/now'
        });
        let parsed = JSON.parse(response);

        let myTime = new Time({
            deviceName: 'PS41',
            deviceConsole: 'PS4',
            startTime: new Date(parsed.currentDateTime),
            endTime: 652585258
        });
        await myTime.save();
        
        res.send('Done');
    } catch (err) {
        res.send(err.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply .. but on npm it says this package is deprecated .. is there are any other ways?